# Having trouble with isEmpty in visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, printing, autofilter

I have a simple script to print all rows of input into a formatted output. I would like to skip any row where column A is empty, but still print if there is data, so row 1 skip, row 2 print, row 3 print, row 4 skip, etc, based on column A.  How can I do that? I have tried numerous codes with no results.  Here is my current working code which prints all.

```
    Sub PrintAllRecords()

    RowCount = Worksheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Worksheets("Print-Auto (2)").Select
    For i = 1 To RowCount
    Range("B1").Value = i
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: @AziMez solved my query.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
Sub PrintAllRecords()

RowCount = Worksheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Worksheets("Print-Auto (2)").Select
For i = 1 To RowCount
   If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & i+1)) Then
      msgbox i
      Range("B1").Value = i
      ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work, it prints the first line only , which has a blank column A, and does not move forward to the next record

Comment: So, can you share a screenshot of your column A contents, please? @JoshLapin.

Comment: [link]https://ibb.co/9nnHJzK

Comment: This is the input data, so in this example the first row to print would be row 8

Comment: @JoshLapin, I have edited the code. Range("A" & i)) will be ==> Range("A" & i+1))

Comment: that worked awesome.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JoshLapin, You are welcome. You can then mark this Answer as "Accepted". https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub PrintAllRecords()

Dim inputSheet As Worksheet: Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input")

RowCount = inputSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Worksheets("Print-Auto (2)").Select
For i = 1 To RowCount
    If Not IsEmpty(inputSheet.Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Range("B1").Value = i
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: you will print out the sheet every time you find a value in colum A...

Comment: I don't disagree, but the question was to specifically skip every row when the cell was empty, which this should do, although why he would want to print every time it wasn't empty is a different question.

Comment: This does not work, it prints the first line only , which has a blank column A, and does not move forward to the next record

Comment: My suspicion would be there is something going on with your RowCount step, it works fine for me.

What this step is doing is going to the bottom of the input sheet in column A and then jumping up to the last populated cell in that column. People generally do this to find the bounds of their dataset. 

So if you only have something in row 1 of column A it will jump up to that and set the row count to 1, then the For loop will run from 1 to 1. Which is what you are seeing happen.

Comment: The Cells(i, 1) part of it is saying do this action in the first column, the 1 represents column A. It needs to be set to the column where the data is so it can find the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

### Print Non-Blanks Using `AutoFilter`

- This will print the rows of the used range where the first column is not blank.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintNonBlanks()
    
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const dFileName As String = "Test.pdf"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CriteriaColumnNumber As Long = 1
    Const CriteriaString As String = "<>" ' non-blanks
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containinig this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Remove any previous filter.
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheets used range.
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = ws.UsedRange
    
    ' Filter first column by non-blanks.
    urg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumnNumber, CriteriaString
    
    ' Test with either...
    urg.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, dFolderPath & dFileName
    ' ... or...
    'ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, dFolderPath & dFileName
    
    ' ... before printing...
    'urg.PrintOut
    ' or...
    'ws.PrintOut
    
    ' Remove the filter.
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Locate the file (folder) in Windows File Explorer.
    'wb.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath
    
End Sub
```